# jQuery addClass to only next specific element - not all on page

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jQuery to animate a hidden element (an image description) to be visible when you hover over an image.

I'm using a code snippet I've found. It works but makes all the hidden image descriptions on the page visible at the same time. I'd like only the relevant one to be viable.

I've been trying to get $(this) and next() to work without fully understanding how it works.

```js
var item = $('p.image-description');

$('.popup-image').hover(
    function () {
        item.addClass('is-visible');

        setTimeout(function () {
            item.addClass('is-open');
        }, 20);
    },
    function () {
        item.removeClass('is-open');

        item.one('transitionend', function (e) {
            item.removeClass('is-visible');
        });
    }
);
```

```css
.masonry-entry .popup-image p.image-description {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.masonry-entry .popup-image p.image-description.is-visible {
  display: block;
}

.masonry-entry .popup-image p.image-description.is-open {
  margin-left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="masonry-entry">
  <a class="popup-image" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
    <p class="image-description">Text here</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="masonry-entry">
  <a class="popup-image" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
    <p class="image-description">Text here</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="masonry-entry">
  <a class="popup-image" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
    <p class="image-description">Text here</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

I'd like to hover over ".popup-image" and only see the relevant "p.image-description". Not all the "p.image-description"'s on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a collection of `.image-description` with the line:

```
var item = $('p.image-description');
```

Whenever you operate on 'item', such as by adding the class 'is-visible', you're applying that to all of the elements in the collection. It would be better to think of what you have now as items rather than item.

You need to use `$(this)` to operate on the element being hovered and find the 'image-description' that you want to add / remove classes from.

Example:

```
$('.popup-image').hover(function () {
    var imageBeingHovered = $(this); // verbosity purely for explanatory purposes
    var imageBeingHoveredDescription = imageBeingHovered.find('.image-description'); // see above - you don't need this many variables, they're solely for clarity.
    imageBeingHoveredDescription.addClass('is-visible');

    setTimeout(function () {
        imageBeingHoveredDescription.addClass('is-open');
    }, 20);
}, function () {
    var description = $(this).find('.image-description'); // shortening for simplicity at this point.
    description.removeClass('is-open');

    description.one('transitionend', function () {
        description.removeClass('is-visible');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan your code is helping, however I have a problem with the hover behaviour. when the page first loads and you hover over an image it all works great. The second time you hover over an image the text stays for short period, then vanishes. Do you know what might cause that? I'm a bit stuck. I've got it on code pen here: [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/studio-steve/pen/LwVmzd)

Comment: I've updated my answer. The `transitionend` event was continuing to fire because I'd  used `on` instead of `one`.

Comment: I should probably have begun by asking this question: are you sure you need JS for this at all? Have you considered using visibility + opacity to achieve the same effect without any JS. Here's a very quick and rough example I threw together based on your code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/voOPwp

Comment: YES! That's much better! Thank you for your help. I only went down the JS route because I couldn't animate from `display:none;` to `display:block;`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

use `this` for showing the specific element and `find` to find the `image-description`

```js
var item = '';
var timeOut = 0;
$('.popup-image').hover( 
        function (e){
       
        item =  $(this).find(' p.image-description');    
       
            item.addClass('is-visible');

             timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
      item.addClass('is-open');
  }, 20);

  },
        function() {
        item =  $(this).find(' p.image-description');    
            item.removeClass('is-open');

            item.one('transitionend', function(e) {
                item.removeClass('is-visible');
        });
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
  }
    );
```

```css
.masonry-entry .popup-image p.image-description{
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s linear;
}
.masonry-entry .popup-image p.image-description.is-visible {
    display: block;
}
.masonry-entry .popup-image p.image-description.is-open {
    margin-left: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="masonry-entry">
    <a class="popup-image" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
        <p class="image-description">Text here</p>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="masonry-entry">
    <a class="popup-image" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
        <p class="image-description">Text here</p>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="masonry-entry">
    <a class="popup-image" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
        <p class="image-description">Text here</p>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it's exactly what I was trying to work out. I couldn't work out the correct use of `&(this)` with a variable. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've just found an issue and I can't work out what it might be. If you hover over an image and then move your cursor over the other images it results in an effect where the text only stays visible for a short period of time. Do you know why that might be? is it something to do with timings? thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I've added `clearTimeout` it seems to solve the problem

Comment: Ram, thank you for your help. I've ended up using Nathan's pure CSS solution. I had just backed myself into a corner. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `$('#my-element').next().first().addClass('my-class');`.

Comment: He had added `var item = $('p.image-description');` as the first line of JS. It might be good to explain why your code works and how he/she can use it to make it work.